# How to group raw sensor data from csv file using python

Tags: python, grouping, tabular

I am getting three types of sensor data from mobile(Accelerometer,Gyroscope and Magnetic field) with the following code (pretty bad as I am just beginning with python, but they are working anyhow :) ).

```
import socket, traceback
host = ''
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

#used for debugging
count=0
print("Success binding")
while count<10:
    message, address = s.recvfrom(5555)
    messageString = message.decode("utf-8")
    print(messageString)
    count=count+1
    with open('yourfile.csv','a') as f:
     f.write(messageString)
     f.close()
```

However the output I am getting in the csv file is like this--

```
205729.68706, 3,   0.464, -0.425,  9.903, 4,  -0.000,  0.001, -0.000, 5,  36.290,  4.707,-24.930205729.88997, 3,   0.443, -0.433,  9.885, 4,  -0.000,  0.001,  0.000205730.09288, 3,   0.465, -0.446,  9.894, 4,  -0.000, -0.000, -0.000, 5,  37.206,  5.412,-24.298205730.29576, 3,   0.468, -0.432,  9.897, 4,  -0.000, -0.000, -0.000, 5,  36.308,  5.411,-25.554205730.49867, 3,   0.442, -0.424,  9.883, 4,   0.000,  0.000, -0.000, 5,  36.868,  4.611,-26.465205730.70155, 3,   0.467, -0.444,  9.888, 4,  -0.000,  0.000, -0.000, 5,  37.498,  5.637,-25.841205730.90446, 3,   0.464, -0.435,  9.904, 4,  -0.001,  0.000, -0.000, 5,  36.301,  5.049,-24.931205731.10734, 3,   0.440, -0.432,  9.876, 4,  -0.000, -0.000, -0.000, 5,  36.308,  5.605,-26.483205731.31026, 3,   0.460, -0.440,  9.906, 4,  -0.000,  0.000,  0.000, 5,  35.706,  5.025,-24.944205731.51317, 3,   0.458, -0.434,  9.909, 4,   0.000,  0.000, -0.000, 5,  35.374,  4.218,-26.492
```

Where the first big number is the timestamp, 3,4,5 are the sensor ids followed by their x,y,z co-ordinate values.
Now this raw data need to be grouped in tabular format by their sensor ids for each time stamp. A meaningful column header will be excellent if it does not require complex coding. I am trying to give a sample below--

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT0qm.jpg)

I have installed veryprettytable from Github but the code or implementation is beyond my python knowledge.
Please help.
I am using python 3.27 latest (June 2018) on windows 10.

Comment: Idk whats going on here, you're using socket for something, and theres a csv invovled, and you give an html example.

Comment: Yeah, and besides that you should really try to reduce the length of your example. 5 or 6 rows of data are fully sufficient for an example.

Comment: please run the html code snippet to get the output format.This is the only quick way I found to express what I want to mean properly.

Comment: i'm still not clear on what the issue is

Comment: A portion of the post required tabular format @SuperStew

Answer (score 0):

this should work in this scenario:

```
while count<10:
    message, address = s.recvfrom(5555)
    messageString = message.decode("utf-8")
    print(messageString)
    count=count+1
    filename = yourfile.xlsx

    workbook = Workbook(filename + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(filename , 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:

        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        print(r)
        for c, col in enumerate(messageString):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: The code need to be modified slightly to avoid syntax and alignment error. A new package 'xlsxwriter' needed to be installed . The code is now: <code>count=count+1
    filename = "yourfile.xlsx"
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(filename , 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for r, row in enumerate(messageString):
            print(r)
        for c, col in enumerate(messageString):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
            workbook.close()</code> Now running in infinite loop produce blank excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output, you need to

- add the desired header information
- strip off unwanted spaces in
  messageString
- append newline to messageString before writing

To do header information you need something like

```
fid = open('yourfile.csv', 'w')
fid.write('timestamp,,accelerometer,,gyroscope,,magnetic field\n')
fid.write(',x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z\n')
fid.close()
```

From the original post it's really hard to tell how messageString is generated. But it's clear you have spaces between fields. You need to strip those somehow. To strip them from the existing messageString use str.replace:

```
messageString = messageString.replace(' ', '') # replace space with empty string
```

Finally, tacking on a newline to messageString is pretty straightforward:

```
messageString += '\n'
```

or

```
messageString = messageString + '\n'
```

Comment: Output file is repeating the header for every record. Also alignment problem for 2nd and third (Gyro & mag) when the output file is opened in excel. The file mode has to be changed to 'a' otherwise only last record is being written.